# I want to change the state value of array while using Redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I know this code is wrong, how to correct it. I am new to Web Dev. Please help !

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name: "cart",
    initialState: {value: {list: []}},
    reducers: {
        addToCart: (state, action) => {
            state.value = action.payload;
        }
    }
})

export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not good to addinCart.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name: "cart",
    initialState: {cart:[]},
    reducers: {
    addToCart: (state, action) => {
        let index=state.cart.findIndex(e=>e.id===action.payload.id); // id should be unique.
        if(index!=-1){
            state.cart[index].qty++;
        }
        
     else {
        let item={...action.payload,qty:1};
        state.cart.push(item);
        }
    }
})

export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

Follow this approach for cart and similarly create removeFromCart reducer too.

Answer (score 0):

At glance looking at your code it might be not returning `state` at glance, try:

```
addToCart: (state, action) => state.value = action.payload
```

Comment: I meant that the change of array value is slightly different in react.js. The code works for integer values, but not array values.

Comment: Because in react arrays are best modified using `setState`